# How to integrate paypal api in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, paypal

I have searched a good tutorial for integrating paypal api in .net core, but I can't find anything that is well explained with the details.

If someone can provide me with one, or has any idea where I can search for, it will be perfect.

Comment: have you looked at their APIs?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#

Comment: Yes, but it's nor working with .net core

Comment: what is the problem? what have you tried? and what error you're facing?

Comment: The problem is that paypal SDK was not supported on .net core before. Now I think it is supported, but i can't find how to intagred it into my website and I need to make a paypal payment.

Comment: why not just use their REST API?

Comment: I was gonna answer myself, but it seems @foyss has done so. He explains it well

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, install the SDK via Nugget. You will also need to create an account on [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/) to grab the client ID, and the secret ID.

As you are using .Net Core, you'll have to fill the Paypal config settings. Example below;
[image]

Next, you will need to create the endpoint (API methods) which creates the payment itself. Best practise is to create it asynchronously as shown below;

[image]

As you can see, there will be many situations that will have to be handled, such as cancelling payments, executing payments, creating payments, taking care of results and so forth... Above is just an example on how it would work with a HTTPGET request.

- Useful [link](https://medium.com/@pmareke/using-paypal-sdk-with-net-core-full-explanation-66aab76cef66)
- Useful link explaining [HTTP Requests](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm)

Comment: Thank you @foyss , I saw this tutorial, it's a good one, but there are a lot of things that I don't know where are they coming from. For example _shipmentService.CreatePayment ... I was searching for somenthng with more details, but I guess I would have to fight with this one.

Comment: Hi @nadia Sorry I couldn't be of much help. I hope the link I provided is of much help to you. The answer by mikaey proves to be quite useful and informatic with a working solution. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/355